# onNewIntent() method called multiple times

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, push-notification, onnewintent

I have below requirement.
I want to create notification.
On tap of notification app should open and navigate to specific fragment based on data received from intent extras.
I need to handle this irrespective of app is in killed state or in foreground.

I have singleTop launch mode set in manifest.

APP KILLED STATE SCENARIO:

It is working well if app is in killed state, it calls onCreate() method and I have screen handling logic in it as well.
But onNewIntent() gets called multiple times thereafter

APP FOREGROUND SCENARIO:

If app is in foreground state then onNewIntent() gets called but without intent extras data.

Please find below code.

To create notification,

```
                notificationIntent.flags = (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                        or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)
                notificationIntent.putExtra(Constants.MEDICATION_EXTRA, titleText)
                contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    context, 0,
                    notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
                )
    
               val id = notificationHelper.postNotification(
                notificationHelper.createNotification(
                    contentText = contentText,
                    contentIntent = contentIntent,
                    autoCancel = true,
                    title = titleText,
                )
            )
```

Comment: change your flags to: 
notificationIntent.flags = (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                    or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)

Comment: Thanks for the reply buddy.
This is not working. If app is in foreground then onNewIntent() fires with empty intent.

Comment: sharing you my working code

`val id = (System.currentTimeMillis()).toInt()

        contentIntent = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            PendingIntent.getActivity(this, id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE)
        } else {
            PendingIntent.getActivity(
                this, id, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
            )
        }`

Comment: How do you know the `Intent` doesn't contain the extras?

Comment: Is there anywhere else in your code that you create a `PendingIntent` for the same `Activity`?

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the issue was that I did not set intent before using it directly.

I was using intent via Acitivity's getter method `getIntent()`.
If I am using intent via the getter method I must set intent received in `onNewIntent(intent:Intent)` method.